# Difference between score and cumulative weight

Tags: tangle

What is the difference between score and cumulative weight (of a transaction), in [IOTA white paper](https://iota.org/IOTA_Whitepaper.pdf)?

Answer (score 4):

Let `x` denote our transaction.

The `score` is backward-looking = weight of `x` + sum of weights of all transactions approved by our transaction `x`

The `cumulative weight` is forward-looking = weight of `x` + sum of weights of all transactions that directly or indirectly approve our transaction `x`